# Enable/Disable the Input of a Software Instrument in Log Pro X Using MIDI?

Tags: midi, logic-pro

I'd like to be able to enable and disable a Software Instrument track's Input using MIDI in Logic Pro X. The idea is to be able to play live guitar with a Behringer FCB1010 (10 footswitches and 2 expression pedals) to control a variety of plugins loaded into separate Software Instrument tracks in Logic. The plugins are processor intensive so it would be good to turn off the ones I'm not using at a particular time.

I read the manual and searched the internet without finding anything that solved my problem. Learn Mode and control surfaces seem close, but I can't get it to recognize the clicking of that button as a controllable thing.

Here's a screenshot of the thing I want to be able to toggle:

[image: screenshot of problem area]

In this screenshot, the "input" for tracks "Cory 3" and "Cory 4" are disabled: their "Archetype" buttons are gray. The "input" for tracks "Goji 3" and "Goji 4" are enabled: their buttons on the same row are blue. The track "Goji 3" is being hovered over (even though the screenshot doesn't show the mouse pointer). It's blue button has become a segmented control whose left most segment with the power icon (0 broken at the top by a 1) toggles the enabled/disabled state of the "input" for that track. I want to be able to enable and disable that by sending a MIDI command like Program Change 88 on Channel 2 from TinyBox Port 1 or something like that.

Comment: idk Logic well, but many DAWs have an option that stops plugins processing if there is no signal input.

Comment: I'm a dinosaur using Logic Pro 9 still, but I assume this will translate to X.  This sounds like something you could do in the environment.  I wish I could give you more specific instructions but I simply don't know my way around it.  I've heard it's capable of all sorts of black magic.